# How to reveal the TOC outline on the left in Xcode4 documentation browser?

Tags: xcode4

In Xcode3 the doc browser had a useful outline on the left splitting a class reference into instance / class methods, properties, tasks, etc.

When I option-click on a symbol in Xcode and then open the full docs browser, I only see the class ref on the right but no table of contents outline on the left. The left side turned into a useless "meta navigation" showing me only high level options such as "iOS 5 Library" or "Xcode 4.2 Developer Library", but the table of contents or class reference outline is missing completely.

It makes it a pain to find something quickly, having to focus on the full-blown class reference on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table of contents and outlines are available on the left side. You just have to click lots of disclosure triangles to get to them. Use the jump bar in the documentation viewer to quickly reach specific areas of the documentation.